# Как создать Bitmap 8 bit с черно-белой палитрой цветов ? C#

Tags: c#, изображения, bitmap

Столкнулся с проблемой, стандартными средствами C# получается создать только Bitmap 8bit, который имеет цветную палитру. Есть ли способ задать черно-белую палитру ?

Comment: Пробовали смешать цвета?

Comment: Это немного не то ) если вы про (R+G+B) / 3)
В 8-ми битном формате нет разделения на RGB, один байт - один пиксель